# Form the query into a double key dictionnary with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query :

```
query = list(collection.aggregate([
    {
     '$match':
         {
            'type':"xml_metadata", 
            'doc_id': {'$regex':"^AZBE"},
            'value.BRKey' :
                {'$in':
                    ["ScanningIncoming",
                    "ScanningClaimIncoming"]
                }
        },
    },
    {
    '$group':
        {
        '_id':
            {
                'ClaimDocumentSubtype':"$value.EcmMetadata.ClaimDocumentSubtype",
                'ContactType':"$value.EcmMetadata.ContactType"
            },
        'count':
            {
                '$sum': 1
            }
        }
    }]))
```

Which gives me this kind of result :

```
[{
    '_id': 
        {'ClaimDocumentSubtype': 'SubType_InfoRequest', 'ContactType': 'Garage'}, 
    'count': 3
},
{
     '_id': 
        {'ClaimDocumentSubtype': 'SubType_Quote', 'ContactType': 'Tierce'},
    'count': 2
}]
```

The thing is I would like to get this kind of result :

```
{<ClaimDocumentSubtype1> {<ContactType1> => <count1>, <ContactType2> => <count2>}, 
<ClaimDocumentSubtype2> {<ContactType1> => <count3>, <ContactType2> => <count4>}, etc}
```

So in the form of a Dictionnary with 2 keys for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator and a final **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline step will get you the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
const pipeline = [
    { '$match': {
        'type':'xml_metadata', 
        'doc_id': {'$regex':'^AZBE'},
        'value.BRKey' : {
            '$in': ['ScanningIncoming', 'ScanningClaimIncoming']
        }
    } },
    { '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'ClaimDocumentSubtype':'$value.EcmMetadata.ClaimDocumentSubtype',
            'ContactType':'$value.EcmMetadata.ContactType'
        },
        'count': { '$sum': 1 }
    } },
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id.ClaimDocumentSubtype',
        'counts': {
            '$push': {
                'k': '$_id.ContactType',
                'v': '$count'
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
      'counts':  { '$arrayToObject': '$counts' }
    } },
    {  '$group': {
        '_id': null,
        'counts': {
            '$push': {
                'k': '$_id',
                'v': '$counts'
            }
        }
    } },
    {  '$replaceRoot': {
        'newRoot': { '$arrayToObject': '$counts' }
    } } 
]
```